# Installing i3-wm overwrote i3gaps?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, i3-window-manager

After cloning `i3gaps` branch and `make && sudo make install`, I ran into graphical errors. So I installed `i3-wm` and went through the installation and entering "N" for each question.

Now, when I have `gap_size 10` in my i3 config, it doesn't work and I get errors. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure i3gaps is a fork, essentially a modified branch of i3. So yes, its i3 or i3-gaps unless you know how to separate them, which I'm afraid I don't.

So, gaps does won't work if running i3wm.

However, as for your i3gaps graphics issue, I'm fairly confident its the standard issue, which should be fixed by adding this at the bottom of your i3config file.

```
for_window [class="^.*"] border pixel 1
```

Source:
http://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/2n43lu/i3_first_time_tiling_wm/

So, remove all i3 stuff, and rebuild and install i3gaps and give it a 2nd shot! :)

Answer (score 0):

i3 gaps fork doesn't yet repair rendering. Rendering of the borders is not going to be "fixed" by i3-wm maintainer as it is firstly a tiling wm and is not crucial for it.

when using config from gaps fork of i3-wm You need to comment/delete options in `.i3/config` that normal i3-wm doesn't have such as

```
gaps inner X
gaps outer X
```

errors You are referencing should be notified in `i3-nagbar` - red dock in top of the display it shows two buttons "show errors" and "edit config". Clickkng *Show errors* button should open* terminal and shows log what is wrong in config.

*) if not, i3-sensible-terminal doesn't properly identify Your terminal emulator - easy way is to set $TERMINAL environmental variable, or install some other. exact precedence of checking terminals that can be opened from `i3-sensible-terminal` is: environmental variable `$TERMINAL`, then executables: `x-terminal-emulator` (debian & derivatives), `urxvt`, `rxvt`, `terminator`, `eterm`, `aterm`, `gnome-terminal`, `roxterm`, `xfce4-terminal`